# Find all $z$ such that $e^{1/z}=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$e^{1/z}=-1$$

From the get go, I can see that if $z$ is a purely real number, this statement can't be true. But I need to show what happens with complex numbers, so below is my attempt.

My question is: is it ok to leave the final answer in the notation below? I know we normally don't leave $i$ in the denominator so I removed it, but then this answer seems kind of sloppy...but then again, I'm not sure.

Taking the natural log of both sides yields:

$$\frac{1}{z}=i\pi + 2\pi i k$$

$$z=\frac{1}{i\pi + 2\pi i k}$$

Rationalizing the denominator:

$$z=\frac{2ki-i}{\pi -4\pi k^2}$$

Comment: you can simplify it by removing $2k-1$ from the nominator and denominator, the answer is ok, wolfram alpha gives the same one https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%281%2Fz%29%3D-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
e^{1/z} &= -1 \iff \\
1/z &= (\pi + 2\pi k) i = (2k + 1) \pi i \\
z &= \frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi i} = -\frac{1}{(2k+1) \pi} \, i
\end{align}
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $z=x+iy$ thus ${1\over z} = {{x-iy}\over {x^2+y^2}}$. $e^{1/z} = e^{{{x-iy}\over {x^2+y^2}}}=-1$. This implies that ${x\over{x^2+y^2}}=0$. Thus $x=0$ and $e^{-iy/y^2}=-1$. Thus $-y/y^2 =\pi+2\pi n$ $n\in Z$. If $y>0$, $-1/y=\pi+2\pi n$ and $y={{-1}\over {\pi+2\pi n}}$. If $y<0$,  $y={{1}\over {\pi+2\pi n}}$.